# Query : Get the previous business day of a day with is_working_day tag

Tags: sql, oracle

We use a materialized view with all days from 01/01/2010 to 31/12/2030.
There is a date field associated with a flag is_working_day 0/1.

I need to get the previous business day of a day.

Example : we are the 01/01/n, previous business day is 31/12/n-1.
We are 02/01/n, previous business day is also 31/12/n-1.

I have some test code here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=215d5e6aa6673f2273f3766f58093bc6

sample table :

```
DATE_D  DAY_OF_WEEK_DESC_EN     IS_WORKING_DAY
01-JAN-10   Friday      0
02-JAN-10   Saturday    0
03-JAN-10   Sunday      0
04-JAN-10   Monday      1
05-JAN-10   Tuesday     1
06-JAN-10   Wednesday   1
07-JAN-10   Thursday    1
08-JAN-10   Friday      1
09-JAN-10   Saturday    0
10-JAN-10   Sunday      0
```

```
select 
date_d, 
lag(date_d) over (order by date_d) as last_working_day, 
day_of_week_desc_en
from oracle_calendar
where is_working_day = 1
```

Expected :

```
DATE_D  LAST_WORKING_DAY    DAY_OF_WEEK_DESC_EN     IS_WORKING_DAY
01-JAN-10               Friday      0
02-JAN-10               Saturday    0
03-JAN-10   04-JAN-10   Sunday      0
04-JAN-10   04-JAN-10   Monday      1
05-JAN-10   04-JAN-10   Tuesday     1
06-JAN-10   05-JAN-10   Wednesday   1
07-JAN-10   06-JAN-10   Thursday    1
08-JAN-10   07-JAN-10   Friday      1
09-JAN-10   08-JAN-10   Saturday    0
10-JAN-10   08-JAN-10   Sunday      0
```

Basicly I use the function LAG() of Oracle to get the previous business day of a business day only, but I have to use the LEAD() function to get the last business day of a closed day. If there are consecutive closed days, I have to use this LEAD() function as many as there is consecutive closed days.

I think there is a better method to get all the previous business day of all consecutive closed days.

Comment: Please include some sample table data along with the expected output.  This would greatly improve your question.

Comment: Why 04-JAN-10 is the previous business day for 03-JAN-10  and  for itself?

Comment: Please do not edit images of data into the question as we can't copy/paste from images so it makes helping you that much harder. If it is not displaying nicely then edit the question to add the appropriate amount of spaces to bring the columns in-line or (better) include DDL/DML statements for the sample data so that we can copy/paste and run them.

Comment: @Serg : Because my code is not really good, expecially when it's the start of the calendar and when there is no business day at the start. If i get the 31/12/n-1 in the calendar (which isn't the case for the moment), the LEAD() function will get the 31/12/n-1 instead of 04/01/n because Monday 04/01/n will have 31/12/n-1 in last_working_day instead of null.
MT0 : all the SQL is on the DBFiddle page. I don't think it's usefull to paste all the code. However, i dont know how to insert a table in here, it look ugly when i copy/paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LAG` with the `IGNORE NULLS` clause and a `CASE` statement:

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE oracle_calendar (
  DATE_D              DATE,
  DAY_OF_WEEK_DESC_EN VARCHAR2(9) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CAST( RTRIM( TO_CHAR( DATE_D, 'Day' ) ) AS VARCHAR2(9) ) ),
  IS_WORKING_DAY      NUMBER(1,0)
);

INSERT INTO oracle_calendar( date_d, is_working_day )
SELECT DATE '2010-01-01', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2010-01-02', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2010-01-03', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2010-01-04', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2010-01-05', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2010-01-06', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2010-01-07', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2010-01-08', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2010-01-09', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2010-01-10', 0 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT date_d, 
       LAG( CASE is_working_day WHEN 1 THEN date_d END, 1, NULL )
         IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY date_d) AS last_working_day, 
       day_of_week_desc_en,
       is_working_day
FROM   oracle_calendar
```

**Output**:

> ```
> DATE_D    | LAST_WORKING_DAY | DAY_OF_WEEK_DESC_EN | IS_WORKING_DAY
> :-------- | :--------------- | :------------------ | -------------:
> 01-JAN-10 | null             | Friday              |              0
> 02-JAN-10 | null             | Saturday            |              0
> 03-JAN-10 | null             | Sunday              |              0
> 04-JAN-10 | null             | Monday              |              1
> 05-JAN-10 | 04-JAN-10        | Tuesday             |              1
> 06-JAN-10 | 05-JAN-10        | Wednesday           |              1
> 07-JAN-10 | 06-JAN-10        | Thursday            |              1
> 08-JAN-10 | 07-JAN-10        | Friday              |              1
> 09-JAN-10 | 08-JAN-10        | Saturday            |              0
> 10-JAN-10 | 08-JAN-10        | Sunday              |              0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=12015dfddc891a283584b4430bef7716)*

**Query 2**:

To get rid of all the `NULL` values at the start and use the first working day:

```sql
SELECT date_d, 
       COALESCE(
         LAG( CASE is_working_day WHEN 1 THEN date_d END, 1, NULL )
           IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY date_d),
         CASE is_working_day
         WHEN 1
         THEN date_d
         ELSE LEAD( CASE is_working_day WHEN 1 THEN date_d END, 1, NULL )
           IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY date_d)
         END
       ) AS last_working_day,
       day_of_week_desc_en,
       is_working_day
FROM   oracle_calendar
```

> ```
> DATE_D    | LAST_WORKING_DAY | DAY_OF_WEEK_DESC_EN | IS_WORKING_DAY
> :-------- | :--------------- | :------------------ | -------------:
> 01-JAN-10 | 04-JAN-10        | Friday              |              0
> 02-JAN-10 | 04-JAN-10        | Saturday            |              0
> 03-JAN-10 | 04-JAN-10        | Sunday              |              0
> 04-JAN-10 | 04-JAN-10        | Monday              |              1
> 05-JAN-10 | 04-JAN-10        | Tuesday             |              1
> 06-JAN-10 | 05-JAN-10        | Wednesday           |              1
> 07-JAN-10 | 06-JAN-10        | Thursday            |              1
> 08-JAN-10 | 07-JAN-10        | Friday              |              1
> 09-JAN-10 | 08-JAN-10        | Saturday            |              0
> 10-JAN-10 | 08-JAN-10        | Sunday              |              0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a585048507128712683fef70b4d1d8bb)*

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is PER-FECT !
without the problem i get with my code.